# Access Purchase Orders via web service

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, acumatica

We are busy developing an interface between Acumatica and our application via the web services. We are developing it in Ruby using the Savon gem.

We've got some of the exports working for the information we need, like this one for Vendor data:

We post the following SOAP call (after logging in):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.acumatica.com/typed/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:Export>
      <tns:commands>
        <tns:Command>
          <tns:FieldName>AcctCD</tns:FieldName>
          <tns:ObjectName>BAccount</tns:ObjectName>
          <tns:Value>Account code</tns:Value>
        </tns:Command>
        <tns:Command>
          <tns:FieldName>AcctName</tns:FieldName>
          <tns:ObjectName>BAccount</tns:ObjectName>
          <tns:Value>Account name</tns:Value>
        </tns:Command>
      </tns:commands>
      <tns:filters/>
      <tns:startRow>0</tns:startRow>
      <tns:topCount>0</tns:topCount>
      <tns:includeHeaders>false</tns:includeHeaders>
      <tns:breakOnError>false</tns:breakOnError>
    </tns:Export>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

to the testing endpoint:

```
http://p3.tryacumatica.com/(W(10003))/Soap/AP303000.asmx?WSDL
```

We are also able to do the same kind of thing for Inventory and Sites. However we're struggling to get it working for Purchase Orders.

We post the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.acumatica.com/typed/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:Export>
      <tns:commands>
        <tns:Command>
          <tns:FieldName>Type</tns:FieldName>
          <tns:ObjectName>POOrder</tns:ObjectName>
          <tns:Value>Type</tns:Value>
        </tns:Command>
        <tns:Command>
          <tns:FieldName>OrderNbr</tns:FieldName>
          <tns:ObjectName>POOrder</tns:ObjectName>
          <tns:Value>Order number</tns:Value>
        </tns:Command>
      </tns:commands>
      <tns:filters/>
      <tns:startRow>0</tns:startRow>
      <tns:topCount>0</tns:topCount>
      <tns:includeHeaders>false</tns:includeHeaders>
      <tns:breakOnError>false</tns:breakOnError>
    </tns:Export>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

to the testing endpoint:

```
http://p3.tryacumatica.com/(W(3))/Soap/PO301000.asmx?WSDL
```

We always just get an empty respone. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get, if to input the same data in form? Which action of the form you try to execute?

Comment: I'm trying to execute the "export" command. I'm not sure how to that on the front-end? Do I use a report to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if PO module is turned on.  Also check to see if the user has rights to query the PO objects.  Does the database receive a query?  One option is debug from the database side.  See if the database picks up an queries submitted from the web service input.
I know these are simple ideas, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a local instance of Acumatica to test on. I'm testing on http://p3.tryacumatica.com, logging in as Admin

It looks like the PO module is turned on, because I can access it from the front-end, and I assume the Admin user has rights, as I can view a list of POs from the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first question is why do you need a FULL list PO ? it could be a huge data.
PO has a composite key - Type, OrderNbr and basically using Export command you have to specify value like EveryOrderNbr

see link below 
[link](http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/844-t210-acumatica-web-services-basic?p=3001#post3001)

Answer (score 0):

+

old c# example for SO

```
            Content SO301000 = context.GetSchema();
        context.Clear();

        string[][] data = context.Export(new Command[] 
        { 
            SO301000.OrderSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryOrderType,
            SO301000.OrderSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryOrderNbr,
            SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType,
            SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr,
            SO301000.OrderSummary.Description,
            SO301000.OrderSummary.Hold,
        }, null,

        new Filter[]
        {

            new Filter { Field = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType, Condition = FilterCondition.Equals, Value = "IN", Operator = FilterOperator.And },
            new Filter { Field = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr, Condition = FilterCondition.Equals, Value = "23630843", Operator = FilterOperator.And }
        },
              0, false, true);
```